# error when ingesting with Watson Discovery Service

Tags: error-handling, data-ingestion, watson-discovery

Trying to ingest a 7MB json file with Watson Discovery Service. When using WDS tooling interface to ingest, the interface indicates successful ingestion, but the document then looks to have failed. The error returned when using the API was: Your request could not be processed because of a problem on the server". The error is not really helping troubleshoot the problem. Any ideas? How do we troubleshoot these problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface indicates successful ingestion because the process is asynchronous. Actually it means that the document was loaded and submitted for ingestion. 
Check if your input json file has a top-level array. Currently this type of json files are not supported so it might be the cause of your issue.